# Excel 2013 List with link to another spreadsheet

Tags: list, hyperlink, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a list box, That when I select a item in the list I am taken to a different spreadsheet and cell. Example If I pick "Pipe 1 inch" on my list it will open my spreadsheet called pipe and display the contents starting at cell A25. Then I would close that sheet and go back to my original spreadsheet, and choose something else "Pipe 2 inch" maybe located at cell A45 in the other spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do exactly what you've described here.

Let's say you create a lookup range of Pipe 1 options in columns A25:A27 of worksheet 'Pipe 1'. Then you create another lookup range of Pipe 2 options in columns A45:A48 of worksheet 'Pipe 2'.
If you use worksheet 'Pipe Orders', with two columns in it called Pipe1 and Pipe2, you can then tie-in those lookup lists to each cell in those columns

Select the top open cell of the Pipe1 column.  Under the Data tab, select DataValidation.  Under the settings tab of that dialog that opens, under the 'Allow' list, select 'List'.  The source box appears and you can enter: 'Pipe 1'$A$25:$A$27, then choose OK.  The single quotes tell Excel to use that particular spreadsheet.

Do the same thing for the next cell over on your Pipe Orders worksheet, which will be the Pipe2 column.  This time when creating your lookup list, use 'Pipe 2'$A$45:$A$48.

You can copy the cell formatting down the page of your Pipe Orders columns to copy this behavior.

This does not give you the links to the other pages, but at least gives you the values.  I experimented a bit with using hyperlinks in the cells for the lookup values, which do work from there, but the links didn't transfer to the pull-down list.